# ¿Es posible tener una carpeta oculta solo para el desarrollador en git?

Tags: git

En ocasiones me han pedido compartir el código por medio de algún repositorio git.

Tengo un projecto de tipo front-end, uso sass, gulp, etc. Todas estas cosas son importantes para mí como desarrollador del maquetado.

Tengo una carpeta *dev* que engloba toda estas configuraciones de desarrollo y otra *dist* donde genero el html final con sus archivos.

¿Cómo puedo compartir solo la carpeta *dist* y que la persona que recibe el repositorio solo pueda descargar aquella carpeta? ¿Es posible en git? ¿O debo crear otro repo git donde vaya metiendo el *dist* por separado?

Gracias

Comment: Entiendo que no usas git para ti mismo, sino solamente para compartir. En este caso, puedes crear un repositorio indicando que la carpeta dev sea ignorado. Esto es hace mediante el fichero [`.gitignore`](http://aprendegit.com/ignorando-ficheros-en-git-parte-i-formas-de-ignorar-ficheros/). Pero como no estoy seguro de que sea el caso, lo dejo como comentario de momento.

Comment: En realidad si lo uso para mi, así llevo el control del versionado. Mi intención es poder tener el control del versionado y no tener dos respos de un mismo proyecto por separado que mantener.

Comment: ¿Pero quieres que la carpeta _dev_ también tenga control de versiones o es algo que modificarás a tu antojo sin importar que esté en git?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [git-submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) o [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree).